# How to increase the size of <a tag letters

Tags: html, css, styling

I have this styling:

```
.content .chapter_text {
    margin-bottom: 0em; 
    padding: 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

.content .chapter_text li{
    list-style-image: url("http://www.comehike.com/img/ui/circle.png");
    margin-left:20px;
}
.content .chapter_text li a {
    color: #7e9940;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
.content .chapter_text a:hover{
    color: #3f6b30;
}
```

I can add font-size:125%; to the `<p>` tag declaration, but I really, just want to make the text of the links bigger.  How could I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.content .chapter_text li a {
    color: #7e9940;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:125%;
}
```

or (all the `<a>`):

```
a {
    font-size:125%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to target all links that are inside a `<p>` tag do this:

```
p a{
    font-size: 125%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target the `a` elements use:

```
a {
    font-size: 125%;
}
```

You can increase the specificity of the selector by prefacing it with its ancestor elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add `font-size: 125%;` to the style declaration for  `.content .chapter_text li a`.